# Excel comparing value from row to different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a Table like this in Sheet1

```
   A          B
1234.jpg |  c1
1234.jpg |  c2
1234.jpg |  c3
3456.jpg |  c8
3456.jpg |  c9
3456.jpg |  c10
haha.jpg |  c2
haha.jpg |  c5
haha.jpg |  c9
```

I need the to match the data according to the Columns in Sheet2 and the data should result something like this.

```
            c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
123.jpg     Y   Y   Y   N   N
3456.jpg    N   N   N   N   N
haha.jpg    N   Y   N   N   Y
```

I am currently only able to make out this

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,0)),"Y","N")
```

Which returns Y as long as A2 matches something from the array. How do I go about matching it as the Column in Sheet2? I'm open to using functions or VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following formula to `D3` cell as per screenshot.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=$C3)*($B$2:$B$10=D$2))=1,"Y","N")
```

[image]

.......................................................................................................................................................
 You can also use this array formula.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C3&D$2,$A$2:$A$10&$B$2:$B$10,0)),"Y","N")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

After entering formula as array formula, drag and drop to right and down as you need.

Comment: I realized that if there are 2 same values in column B for one jpg it would show as N instead. Anyway to resolve that?